# Incorrect output using html "sub" tag

Tags: html, drupal, output, transform, nowrap

Why does this `[A]<sub>0</sub>(M)` yield output as if it were `[A<sub>0</sub>] (M)`? The html is being run on a site that uses Drupal 6.x. I'm not sure if that has anything to do with the problem. I used to have it in the format `[A<sub>0</sub>] (M)`, but I am trying to change it to `[A]<sub>0</sub>(M)`. I also used a text transform to rotate the text, so I thought my browser may have been caching the transform, so I cleared my cache (nothing happened). The transform serves to make a y-axis label for a graph. I also removed the transform and tried it (same result without rotation). Problem also occurs in multiple browsers. The html/php is saved with extension `-static.tpl.php`. The code is being used as a custom drupal module that can be made embeddable in a drupal page. As of right now, the module resides within its own page. Any input is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Here is the local code block:

```
<td style = "white-space: nowrap;">
  <div id = "yAxisLabel" style = "width: 20px; height: 20px; -webkit-transform: rotate(-90deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-90deg); -ms-transform: rotate(-90deg); 
    -o-transform: rotate(-90deg);">
      [A]<sub>0</sub>(M)
  </div>
</td>
```

[image]

I have found that the text inside of the `yAxisLabel` div is not updating if that helps with any problems.

Comment: Of course brackets are not moved that way in rendering, and `<sub>` is not rendered as `<sub>` but causes subscript style. If the transforms are relevant to the issue, explain how. If not, drop them.

Comment: "Where" in drupal? The square brackets may have a meaning. Are you using tokens? Need more info to help. ( BTW: &nbsp or &nbsp; ? )

Comment: To miguel...I used to need &nbsp for spacing, but since I put nowrap, I no longer need it. I changed the post. How can I tell if I am using tokens? Also added information about how I am using the code in drupal. I am fairly new to drupal and don't know my way around well yet. To Jukka...I thought the transform may have been relevant if the browser was storing information about it to re-use. I will post a picture of the final screen result. Sorry I don't have enough rep to @ both of you

Answer (score 0):

I am extremely sorry! I forgot that I recently added functionality for changing y-axis labels in my JavaScript, and I forgot to update it. Stupid me. Thank you all for your time.